# Error attaching icon when sending notify-send to Linux from Pycharm

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, notify-send

I want to send `notify-send` with icon to Linux from Python, but when I do it from PyCharm's Terminal or from `subprocess.run(command, shell=True)` with Python, I get an empty icon instead of my icon.

It works when I run it from Linux (being in the same directory as in PyСharm's terminal).

The icon is located in the `~/PycharmProjects/SomeProject/icons/` directory. So I ran this:

```
notify-send --urgency normal -i ~/PycharmProjects/SomeProject/icons/someicon.png 'Notification text'
```

And in Python I do this:

```
import subprocess

command = "notify-send --urgency normal -i ~/PycharmProjects/SomeProject/icons/someicon.png 'Notification text'"
subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: Are you running this in a VM or on a computer booting Linux? I get an error on Windows Subsystem Linux saying invalid machine ID.

Comment: @MichaelHearn On a computer booting Linux (Zorin OS 16.1).